# Uncaught ReferenceError: ReduxBehaviour is not defined

Tags: redux, polymer, redux-thunk

uncaught syntax and reference error

[image]

My project is working fine in local host but after firebase deploy redux is not working,please somebody help to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is primarily comes when the redux.js file is not found or not available in the specified location.

It might happen that you would have excluded the files from your firebase.json during deployment. Please check if you have any ignore rules in firebase.json.